# Copying a part of Simd::View

Tags: c++, image, algorithm, image-processing, simd-library

I use [Simd::View](http://ermig1979.github.io/Simd/help/struct_simd_1_1_view.html) class from [Simd Library](http://github.com/ermig1979/Simd). It is a container which holds an image. I need to copy a part (the right bottom corner) of image into another image.

As I know there is a function [Simd::Copy](http://ermig1979.github.io/Simd/help/group__copying.html#gadc21a4c5957a3e002edaa04721d952e2) which allows to copy one image to other. But it copies image as whole. Of course I could write my own function to do this. But maybe anybody know any good-looking solution of this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use method [Simd::View::Region](http://ermig1979.github.io/Simd/help/struct_simd_1_1_view.html#ab8114c875d686dd01fecaa4fa5e791f4). It returns reference to subregion in given image.
So you can easy copy this subregion with using of [Simd::Copy](http://ermig1979.github.io/Simd/help/group__copying.html#gadc21a4c5957a3e002edaa04721d952e2):

```
#include "Simd/SimdLib.hpp"

int main()
{
    typedef Simd::View<Simd::Allocator> View;
    View a(200, 200, View::Gray8);
    View b(100, 100, View::Gray8);
    // Copying of a part (the rigth bottom corner) of image a to the image b:
    Simd::Copy(a.Region(b.Size(), View::RightBottom), b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh it's really what I need!

Answer (score 0):

There is a function named [Simd::CopyFrame](http://ermig1979.github.io/Simd/help/group__copying.html#ga37f00c290856c9075c5facb69cd3f867)
which accepts source, **bounding frame** and destination as input parameters. Using this function you may be able to copy the bottom right corner of your input image to another output image.

The bounding frame can be created by using [Simd::Rectangle()](http://ermig1979.github.io/Simd/help/struct_simd_1_1_rectangle.html).

Comment: Unfortunately this function makes opposite action - it copies all except given region.

Comment: For creating the bounding rectangle you can subtract total frame height from expected bounding rectangle height and same for width.